# Why does XCode Command Line Tools take up so much space?

Tags: xcode, memory, space, command-line-tool

I don't know the ins and outs of UNIX-like dev tools, but I am just wondering why does the command line tools alone take up a whopping 170MB on my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the Unix development tools, the Xcode Command Line Tools also installs the OS X SDK frameworks and headers. I think they are what's taking most of that space.